# Challenge: elegantly LINQify this procedural code

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

```
string[] filesOfType1 = GetFileList1();
string[] filesOfType2 = GetFileList2();
var cookieMap = new Dictionary<string, CookieContainer>();

Action<string, Func<string, KeyValuePair<string, CookieContainer>>> addToMap = (filename, pairGetter) =>
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, CookieContainer> cookiePair;
        try
        {
            cookiePair = pairGetter(filename);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error was encountered while trying to read " + file + ".");
            return;
        }

        if (cookieMap.ContainsKey(cookiePair.Key))
        {
            if (cookiePair.Value.Count > cookieMap[cookiePair.Key].Count)
            {
                cookieMap[cookiePair.Key] = cookiePair.Value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cookieMap.Add(cookiePair.Key, cookiePair.Value);
        }
    };


foreach (string file in filesOfType1)
{
    addToMap(file, GetType1FileCookiePair);
}
foreach (string file in filesOfType2)
{
    addToMap(file, GetType2FileCookiePair);
}
```

Salient features that must be preserved:

- Files of type 1 are more important than files of type 2; i.e. if a file of type 1 maps to a (key, value1) combination and a file of type 2 maps to a (key, value2) combination, then we add (key, value1) to cookieMap and *not* (key, value2). **Edit: as pointed out by Bevan, this is not satisfied by my original procedural code.**
- Secondarily, `CookieContainer`s with a higher `Count` have higher priority, i.e. if there are two (key, value) combos for the same key and both from the same filetype, we choose the one with higher `value.Count`.
- Per-case exception handling is a must; screwing up a single file-reading should just allows us to note that and continue.

My best attempt started like this:

```
var cookieMap = (filesOfType1.Select(file => GetType1FileCookiePair(file))
                .Concat(filesOfType2.Select(file => GetType2FileCookiePair(file))))
                    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key)
                    .Select(/* some way of selecting per the above bullets */)
                    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

But it's inelegant and filling in that comment block seems like a bitch. Right now I'm happy to stay procedural, but I thought that it might be a fun challenge to see if people can come up with something really clever.

Comment: From what I can see, the original code you show doesn't satisfy your "files of type 1 are more important than files of type 2" constraint - if a type 2 file has a higher count, the code will overwrite a type 1 cookie container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt - seemed simplest to split the task into three distinct statements.

I'm using a helper function that returns null if the action throws an exception - for consistency with the answer from Omer van Kloeten, I've called this Swallow()

Also, I'm not using the LINQ syntax, just the extension methods provided by System.Linq.Enumerable

Lastly, note that this is uncompiled - so take it as intent.

```
// Handle all files of type 1
var pairsOfType1 = 
    filesOfType1
        .Select( file => Swallow( pairGetter(file)))
        .Where( pair => pair != null);

// Handle files of type 2 and filter out those with keys already provided by type 1
var pairsOfType2 =
    filesOfType2
        .Select( file => Swallow( pairGetter(file)))
        .Where( pair => pair != null);
        .Where( pair => !pairsOfType1.Contains(p => p.Key == pair.Key));

// Merge the two sets, keeping only the pairs with the highest count
var cookies =
    pairsOfType1
        .Union( pairsOfType2)
        .GroupBy( pair => pair.Key)
        .Select( group => group.OrderBy( pair => pair.Value.Count).Last());
        .ToDictionary( pair => pair.Key);
```

Comment: Where( pair => !pairsOfType1.Contains(p => p.Key == pair.Key)); is incorrect, because it filters out pairs that have a higher count in type2 without checking.

Comment: Check out the original question - Domenic wrote "Files of type 1 are more important than files of type 2", so the Where clause is correct, though the original code didn't satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Why do you need to `Where` calls for type 2? Is an `&&` condition not enough?

Comment: @Hosam - Yes, I could have used && instead of two Where calls, would have the same effect; I just prefer how it looks having a series of simpler tests, instead of one more complex test. YMMV.

Comment: That is some clever LINQ right there, especially the third part. +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
using CookiePair = KeyValuePair<string, CookieContainer>;
using CookieDictionary = Dictionary<string, CookieContainer>;

Func<string[], Func<string, CookiePair>, IEnumerable<CookiePair>> getCookies =
  ( files, pairGetter ) =>
    files.SelectMany( filename => {
      try { return new[] { pairGetter( filename ) }; }
      catch { Console.WriteLine( "..." ); return new CookiePair[0]; }
    } );

var type1Cookies = getCookies( filesOfType1, GetType1FileCookiePair ).ToArray( );
var type1CookieNames = type1Cookies.Select( p => p.Key ).ToArray( );
var type2Cookies = getCookies( filesOfType2, GetType2FileCookiePair )
  .Where( p => !type1CookieNames.Contains( p.Key ) );

var cookieMap = type1Cookies.Concat( type2Cookies )
  .Aggregate( new CookieDictionary( ), ( d, p ) => {
    if( !d.ContainsKey( p.Key ) || p.Value.Count > d[p.Key].Count )
      d[p.Key] = p.Value;
    return d;
  } );
```

**Edit:** Updated cookie retrieval to satisfy the "files of type 1 are more important than those of type 2" requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse my not actually going ahead and compiling this, but this is the way I'd go around to doing it:

```
var cookieMap = (from pair in
                     (from f1 in filesOfType1
                      select Swallow(() => GetType1FileCookiePair(f1)))
                         .Concat(from f2 in filesOfType2
                                 select Swallow(() => GetType2FileCookiePair(f2)))
                         .SelectMany(dict => dict)
                 group pair by pair.Key into g
                 select g)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(pair => pair.Value)
                                                .OrderByDescending(value => value.Count)
                                                .First());
```

`Swallow` follows:

```
private static T Swallow<T>(Func<T> getT)
{
    try { return getT(); } catch { }

    return default(T);
}
```

Love me a good LINQ.

- **Edit:** Added a `Swallow` method that will swallow all exceptions.
- **Edit 2:** Compiled, altered, etc. Added `Swallow`. Now works as intended.

Comment: Also I think Max will return a double.

Comment: Edited re exceptions.
IIRC, Max has a generic overload.